# Is it possible to calculate $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$ if the domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is defined as "all reals except number zero"?

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

Is following reasong correct?

We can't find definite integral on discontinious part of function. Yet as far as I understand, when we talk about continuity of a function we mean continuity over the domain of said function. So if we change domain we can make discontinous function continious. Like by excluding zero from domain of 1/x we will make said function continious over its domain. After this it would be possible to find 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$$

Comment: A precondition for definition of Riemann integral $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$ is that $f$ is defined over $[a, b] $ and that $f$ is bounded on this interval. The problem here is that however you try to define $f(0)$ the function remains unbounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**.

It is not enough for a function to be continuous on a (*non-closed*) interval for it to be integrable over that same interval. The function must also be **bounded**. Your function is not bounded. The Riemann integral of that function does not exist, including or excluding $0$.

Another way of thinking is that a single point has *no effect* on an integral. That is, if $f$ is equal to $g$ on all points except one, the integral of $f$ and $g$ will be equal. This statement can actually be expanded to saying that if $f$ and $g$ are equal on all points except for a countable many of them, their integrals will be equal. If you know a bit of measure theory, then an even stronger statement applies, since the integrals will be equal if $f$ and $g$ differ only on a set with measure $0$.

Comment: "The function must also be bounded." Doesn't it contradict to fact that we can find definite integral $\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac{1}{x}dx$? If you were right we wouldn't be able to calculate it because 1/x isn't bounded function.

Comment: @user161005 The function $\frac1x$ is bounded on $[-2,-1]$.

Comment: I see, you meant "bounded on given interval". After remembering graph of 1/x I agree that the function isn't bounded on [-1;1]

Comment: But what if we excluded [-1;1] from the domain of 1/x? Would we be able to calculate $\int_{-10}^{10}\frac{1}{x}dx$ ?

Comment: @user161005 No, because you cannot integrate a function that is not defined on a subinterval of $[a,b]$.

Comment: I rolled back on the edit as I believe the inital answer by 5xum more correct by stating the interval.

Comment: @Kevin What are you talking about? If stating interval is "more correct" then by your own logic your edit made it worse by removing explicitly stated interval

Comment: @user161005 Exaclty, thanks

Comment: @user161005 Editing your question to the point at which an already posted answer becomes incorrect is usually not advisable.

Comment: By the way changing a function on countably many points does affect its Riemann integrability (but not Lebesgue integrability).

Comment: @5xum I didn't edit my question, I edited your answer, making your assumption about interval explicit

Comment: @5xum Sorry, I just forgot to accept it. Just check its edition history and you will find what exactly I improved.